# Cannot center my nav bar and add a bottom border to active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I've been trying to centre my navbar and add a line under the active page but it does not work. Any advice would be appreciated. I've added border bottom to active element and display `inline-block` to the ul but it doesn't do the trick, why is that?

```
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">AGENDA</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CASE MANAGEMENT</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICE DIRECTORY</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);

}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav ul{
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
   font-size: small;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
   border-width: 0px;
   border-radius: 0px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
  border-bottom:1px solid #771e65;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #e4e5e6;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/judison/dk46p6pz/

Comment: your **JSFiddle** is quite a mess!! review your **DOM** too.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Styles go here */

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #771e65;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #e4e5e6;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav li > a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav li > a:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #771e65;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">AGENDA</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CASE MANAGEMENT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICE DIRECTORY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check this out...

Just add `text-center` class on `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">` like `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">`

and after that change your css like

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav li > a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav li > a:focus {
  border-bottom:1px solid #771e65;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it really difficult..
Just add this

```
.collapse ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
.collapse ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.collapse ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.collapse{
  text-align: center;
}
```

And delete this

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

You don't have to select all **classes** and **IDs**, just that primary. **Display** doesn't work for you, because you have select just **ul**. And **list-style-type** doesn't work because you have still select just **ul**.. For list-style-type you have to select **li**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you allready have your `active` link underlined, you just don't have the `active` class on any link here as an example.

And to center your links review these rules: and See working example.

```
/***Added CSS***/
 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-color: rgba(228, 229, 230, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(119, 30, 101, 1);
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #771e65;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #e4e5e6;
}
/***Added CSS***/

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">AGENDA</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DOCUMENT MANAGEMENT</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CASE MANAGEMENT</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICE DIRECTORY</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```